# Read string of any length in C

Tags: beginner, c, strings, io

I've written code in C for reading a string of any length, and printing the string. It's one of my first C programs. I posted the program as part of a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926208/why-do-i-have-to-press-ctrl-d-three-times-to-quit-a-program-during-an-input?noredirect=1), and received a comment:

> ... there are many things wrong with your C version.

I'd really like to know what is wrong with the function I have written. Suspects: EOF handling, calling dynamic memory allocation functions too many times.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Asks the user for string input.
 * Returns a pointer to the string entered by the user.
 * The pointer must be freed.
 */
char* input()
{
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char));  /* For the null character */
    if (s == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: malloc\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    s[0] = '\0';

    /* Read characters one by one */
    char ch;
    size_t s_len = 0;
    while((ch = (char) getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (ch == EOF) {
            exit(0);
        }
        s_len++;
        s = realloc(s, (s_len * sizeof(char)) + sizeof(char));
        if (s == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: realloc\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        s[s_len - 1] = ch;
        s[s_len] = '\0';
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Name: ");
    char *s = input();
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the code work, to the best of your knowledge?

Comment: @Null Yes it works.

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1.

Comment: @200_success Understood. I've posted the improved version as a GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/flux77/9892a7dfb930935168059abe624aeae7

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is **1**, since sizes are measured in units of `char`.  Use that fact to reduce obfuscation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ```
> /* Asks the user for string input.
>  * Returns a pointer to the string entered by the user.
>  * The pointer must be freed.
>  */
> ```

Slightly misleading in that this function doesn't *ask* for input. (As written it is not responsible for printing the prompt.)

Perhaps also should clarify the intended behavior:

- If there is input that is not terminated by a newline, is that string returned?
- When input is terminated with a newline, is the newline preserved in the returned string?

> ```
> char* input()
> {
>     char *s = malloc(sizeof(char));  /* For the null character */
> ```

In C, `char` *by definition* is 1 byte. `sizeof (char)` is unnecessary and adds visual noise.

> ```
>     if (s == NULL) {
>         fprintf(stderr, "Error: malloc\n");
>         exit(1);
> ```

It's usually considered poor behavior if calling a library function causes the entire program to terminate.  You should return an error value (e.g. `NULL`) and leave that decision up to the caller.

> ```
>     }
>     s[0] = '\0';
>
>     /* Read characters one by one */
>     char ch;
> ```

`ch` must be an `int`.  `getchar` returns an `int` precisely so that it can return a value outside the range of `char` (technically `unsigned char`) to indicate failure (i.e., the `EOF` value).  Otherwise you would not be able to distinguish `EOF` from a legitimate byte value.

> ```
>     size_t s_len = 0;
>     while((ch = (char) getchar()) != '\n') {
>         if (ch == EOF) {
> ```

It's more idiomatic to check for `EOF` in the loop condition and then check for character values inside the loop body:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (ch == '\n') {
        ...
```

Checking for `EOF` in the loop condition allows you to safely truncate `ch` to `char` throughout the entire loop body, which makes it a bit easier to reason about.

> ```
>             exit(0);
> ```

Same thing here about terminating the program.  It's especially weird here since this exits with a *success* code and doesn't return the string to the caller.

> ```
>         }
>         s_len++;
>         s = realloc(s, (s_len * sizeof(char)) + sizeof(char));
> ```

Never do `x = realloc(x, ...)`.  If `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`, you will have lost the old value of `x` and will be unable to free it, resulting in a memory leak.  You instead should use a temporary variable:

```
char* newBuffer = realloc(s, ...);
if (newBuffer == NULL) {
  ...
}
s = newBuffer;
```

Again, `sizeof (char)` is noise.  You additionally should generally avoid `sizeof (Type)`; it's not robust if the types change since you would need to edit more places (and neglecting to do so could lead to *silent* buffer overflows and introduce security vulnerabilities).  It's better to use `sizeof expression` where *expression* is based on the corresponding *variable*.  For example, if you want the code to be robust if the type of `s` changes (e.g. if you wanted to adapt the code to support `wchar_t`), you should do:

```
char* newBuffer = realloc(s, (s_len + 1 /* NUL */) * sizeof *s);
...
```

Finally, calling `realloc` for *every* byte read is grossly inefficient.  A better approach is to maintain a buffer where you keep track of its allocated size and to grow it exponentially (e.g. doubling in size) whenever you need more space.

> ```
>         if (s == NULL) {
>             fprintf(stderr, "Error: realloc\n");
>             exit(1);
> ```

Same thing about terminating the program.  Also should do `free(s);` along this path.

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     printf("Name: ");
> ```

I/O is normally buffered.  You should call `fflush(stdout)` afterward to ensure that the prompt is printed to the screen before waiting for input.

Comment: Regarding `getchar()`: after checking that the character is not `\n` or `EOF`, can I safely cast the int to a char? I mean at some point I would have to place chars into the char array that will be returned.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've written an improved version based on your advice: https://gist.github.com/flux77/9892a7dfb930935168059abe624aeae7

Comment: @Flux Yes, after checking that the character is not `EOF`, you can safely cast it to a `char`. (That is also why checking for `EOF` in the loop condition is more idiomatic.  I've updated my answer to mention this.)

Comment: @jamesdlin My reading of the standard is that you can safely cast it to `unsigned char`, but you can't safely cast it to `signed char` or `char`. Reading with `getchar` into a `char` array is surprisingly harder than it should be. You could write `((unsigned char *)s)[pos] = ch`, but it isn't even guaranteed that `char` can represent as many values as `unsigned char` – despite the fact that `fgets` and friends take `char *` pointers, not `unsigned char *`. It's not something that a beginner should have to think about, but if you're a stickler for portability then technically you have to...

Comment: @benrg Oops. Yes, `fgetc`/`getchar` returns a `char` as an `unsigned char`, and you would need to alias `s` as you describe. That said, I think casting the result of `fgetc`/`getchar` to `unsigned char` and then `char` *usually* should be good enough (the `unsigned char` to `char` cast is implementation-defined, but I think you'd have to find a very pathological implementation that doesn't preserve the bits).  Additionally, a pathological implementation *could* define `sizeof (int) == 1` with `CHAR_BIT >= 16`, in which case the usual idiom for checking for EOF isn't strictly correct either. =/

Comment: I have to disagree that "*`sizeof (char)` is unnecessary and adds visual noise.*" To me, it is much more self-documenting to express the size in terms of `sizeof(char)` than to use a magic number of 1.

Comment: @CodyGray If it needs to be expressed in terms of the size of each element, then `sizeof *s` (or equivalent) should be preferred.  Additionally, if your intent is to allocate a number of *bytes*, it's seems silly to multiply a length by the size of a byte, and a byte is what `char` *is*.

Comment: "so that it can return a value outside the range of char to indicate failure" --> No.  `EOF` can readily have the value of -1 in a _signed_ `char` implementation and so `EOF` _is_ representable by a `char` there.  Better would be "so that it can return a value outside the range of `unsigned char` to indicate failure".

Comment: @chux Good point.  Fixed (sort of).  Wording it is slightly awkward since the point is to explain why `getchar` returns an `int` instead of `char` (whether signed or unsigned). =/

Comment: @jamesdlin I often say `int` is returned to distinguish typically 1 of 257 conditions: an `EOF` or `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 5):

***String* vs. *line***

> Read string of any length in C

User input in C is better described as reading a *line* than a *string*.

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.
>
> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line
> consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character.  Whether the
> last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. C11dr §7.21.2 2

After reading a *line*, input is converted to a *string* by appending a *null character*.  The appended *null character* is part of the *string*, but not user input.

***Null characters***

The tricky bit is what happens when reading input that itself contains a *null character*?  Rare, but not prevented in code.

OP's approach of `char* input()` fails to always provide unambiguous length information.

With `char *s = input();`, code does not know if the first *null character* encountered in `s` is the appended one or a read one.

Conveying length resolves this issue.

```
char* input(size_t *sz) { 
  *sz = 0;
  ....
  *sz = s_len;
  return s;
} 

size_t sz = 0;
char *s = input(&sz);

printf("Length of input:%zu\n", sz);
```

---

**Consider defensive programming.**

Reading strings of *any* length allows a nefarious user to overwhelm system memory resources with a *lengthy* input - perhaps gigabytes.

The nature of user input, IMO, should have a *generous* upper bound.  In which case, code can simply use `fgets()` (not withstanding the above *null character* issue.)

```
#define USER_NAME_SZ 4096

char name[USER_NAME_SZ];
if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin)) {
  if (strlen(name) >= USER_NAME_SZ - 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Hostile input detected\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
```

**Exit on end-of-file?**

OP's code exits the program on end-of-file - a rude thing for `input()` to do.

```
if (ch == EOF) {
  // exit(0);
  if (feof(stdin)) {
    if (s_len > 0) return s; // Return what was read
    free(s);
    return NULL;             // Let caller cope with end-of-file.
  }
```

**`EOF`: end-of-file or error?**

Rarely `getchar()` returns `EOF` due to an *input error*.

> If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and `getchar` returns `EOF`. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `getchar` returns `EOF`.

It is [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45264457/2410359) to distinguish using `feof()` than `ferror()`.

So rather than simply exit on `EOF`, code may want to distinguish.

```
if (ch == EOF) {
  // exit(0);
  if (feof(stdin)) {
    if (s_len > 0) return s; // Return what was read
    free(s);
    return NULL;
  }

  // This is trickier - what to do on input error?
  // Different schools of thought exist.
  // Usual, like fgets(), return NULL
  free(s);
  return NULL;
}
```

Calling code sample usage:

```
char *s = input();
if (s) {
  puts(s);
} else {
  if (feof(stdin)) puts("end-of-file");
  else puts("end-of-file");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid trying to combine assignment and compare in the same statement. The cast within the statement makes it even hard to read.

Also, handle EOF with getchar.  You can get EOF with redirected input.

Instead of this:

```
while((ch = (char) getchar()) != '\n') {

    . . .
}
```

This:

```
int value = getchar();
ch = (char)value;
while (value != EOF and ch != '\n') {
    ...

    value = getchar();
    ch = (char)value;
}
```

Comment: Calling `getchar()` from two places is worse, in my opinion. `while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF ) { }` is correct idiomatic C to scan a file.

Comment: This is way more error-prone (there's duplicate code, and it's easy to accidently compare `ch != EOF`).  It'd be much better to restrict the cast version to be within the loop body.  If you *really* want to avoid the assignment in the loop condition, IMO it's be better to have `while (true) { int ch = getchar(); if (ch == EOF) break; ...`

Comment: Code is more direct with `while ((value = getchar()) != EOF and value != '\n') {`.

Answer (score -2):

Realistically, you would want to check that the input characters are acceptable to your program.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean? Are you suggesting ensuring that if `getchar()` doesn't return EOF the they should ensure it's only 8 bits? Isn't that guaranteed by `getchar()`? If that's not what you mean, what do you mean?